# How can I create a button for a django admin action?

Tags: django, django-admin-actions

I have a django admin action say "refresh", I want to add a refresh button for each row in the admin list view. I can create button using format_html but how can I invoke "refresh" action when it is pressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `admin actions` are the best fit in this case.

[Actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#admin-actions) are

> simple functions that get called with a list of objects selected on the change list page

With the buttons you describe however, you want to operate on a single row/instance.
Therefore I would simply [create a custom url endpoint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) for your `ModelAdmin` which is called when you press the button and which handles the desired action.

[This article](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-add-custom-action-buttons-to-django-admin-8d266f5b0d41#.5sc9oa4yf) has quite a comprehensive overview how this can be done in detail.

Comment: It works. I actually need it as a django action too. Button is good for one row         because selecting one row then selecting action and clicking OK is three steps compared to clicking just one button. Thank You.

Comment: There is a functionality called message_user which notifies when an admin action is finished. Is it possible to mimic this functionality using custom url? I  am redirecting back to list page after clicking refresh.

Comment: `message_user` seems to be simply a helper for the messages framework which can be used independently of admin actions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message